# How to filter language for cloning multiple GitHub repositories with curl?

Tags: git, curl, github, clone

I am working in an organization with about 500 repositories in enterprise GitHub. I found some curl to clone all of the repositories at once but I cannot seem to find a way to filter the script by language. This is the curl I am using:

`curl -s -H "Authorization: token [token]" https://github.[company].com/api/v3/orgs/[organization]/repos?page=1&per_page=100 | jq '.[].ssh_url' | xargs -n 1 git clone`

It works fine to clone every repo but obviously that is not efficient when I just need specific languages. I have tried every variation I have seen suggested in my searches, such as including the **/search/repositories/** string, and **?language=** and **?q=language:** parameters in the URL. It just skips the filter completely and still returns the full list of repos, results in a basic JSON response for the organization, or it comes back with a "Not Found" message.

Does anyone know how to filter by language in this instance, or maybe have a better solution for cloning multiple repos filtered by language? I am trying to automate some processes in Jenkins and/or Docker that need to search and parse across all of the target repos.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether or not it's possible to filter this as part of the API request, but you can certainly perform the filtering with `jq`. For example, I can get a list of SSH urls for my Python projects like this:

```
curl -s -H "Authorization: token $token" https://api.github.com/user/repos |
  jq  '.[]|select(.language = "Python").ssh_url'
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. It took me a bit because that solution specifically was not working for some reason. But when I did (.language | contains("Java")) rather than the equals, it worked. I am also realizing that I am not getting a full list of my organization's repos, plus a lot of null languages, which I have to look into. Marking this as answered because using jq to filter is the solution to the question.